# Why is QMultiMap's find operation not working as I expected?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QMultiMap<QDateTime, SomeOwnDataType>` from which I'd like to retrieve all values with a certain timestamp. This is what I do:

```
QMap<QDateTime, Appointment>::iterator it = _reminders.find(now);
```

where `now` has a value of *di 6. mrt 12:07:00 2012*. This is my loop condition:

```
while (it != _reminders.end() && it.key() == now) {
```

This was the state of the `_reminders` object:

[image: Debug]

Contrary to my expectations, the loop was skipped entirely. How come?

Comment: Is "it" pointing to "_reminders.end()" after the find or a valid item?

Comment: I checked the condition of `it == _reminders.end()` before going into the loop. It was true, which is why the loop is never executed. But why? Could the comparison operator of `QDateTime` have something to do with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that the two timestamps are not equal. If you check the `==` operator code of `QDateTime` you will see that the equality holds if both time and date are equal.

```
bool QDateTime::operator==(const QDateTime &other) const
{
    if (d->spec == other.d->spec && d->utcOffset == other.d->utcOffset)
        return d->time == other.d->time && d->date == other.d->date;
    else {
        QDate date1, date2;
        QTime time1, time2;

        d->getUTC(date1, time1);
        other.d->getUTC(date2, time2);
        return time1 == time2 && date1 == date2;
    }
}
```

But the time equal operator compares miliseconds:

```
bool operator==(const QTime &other) const { return mds == other.mds; }
```

where `mds` is the time in miliseconds. In the `QTime` constructor `mds` is calculated as follows:

```
 mds = (h*SECS_PER_HOUR + m*SECS_PER_MIN + s)*1000 + ms;
```

It would be safer if you just checked if the difference between two timestamps is within a limit. For example :

```
while (it != _reminders.end() && abs(now.msecsTo(it.key())) < aLimitInMsecs) {
```

Comment: D'oh... it didn't occur to me to check the msec component since I don't use them. I'm going to fix this by setting the milisecond component to 0 on all timestamps. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

How do you initialize `now`?

`QDateTime` goes up to the millisecond, so a `toString()` could display the same value while actually the values are different...
Unless at some point the key _reminders[0] is set to the value of `now`, they will be different.

If you are constructing an calendar app, you might use a `QString` as the key to your `QMultiMap`, with the values being the output of `QDateTime::toString()` (the format depending on the precision you are willing (day, hours, minute, ...)